# 2 linear systems: same solution set implies row equivalence; how to prove?

Tags: linear-algebra

How does one prove that if 2 systems of linear equations $Ax=c_1$ and $Bx=c_2$ have the same solution set, then they are row equivalent?

I see that it's true from [wikipedia:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations)

> [...] two linear systems are equivalent if and only if they have the same solution set.

**Original question before edits:**

For fixed $m$ and $n$, is it possible to have two $m$ by $n$ matrices $A$ and $B$ that are not row equivalent but have the same solution set? What about if $A$ and $B$ are allowed to be of differing dimensions?

Comment: A matrix doesn't have a solution set; rather, an equation has a solution set. I assume you mean the solution set of the homogeneous matrix equations $Ax=0$ and $Bx=0$, that is, the null spaces of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ have different dimensions then it's very possible: for example, $A$ could be a single row and $B$ could be multiple copies of that row.

Comment: @Greg has answered your question for the differing-dimension case, e.g., the system $x+y=2$ is not row-equivalent to the system $x+y=2,x+y=2$, but it has the same solutions.

Comment: The solution set to $Ax=c_1$ is just an affine shift of the solution set to $Ax=0$. So if $Ax=c_1$ and $Bx=c_2$ have the same solution sets, then so do $Ax=0$ and $Bx=0$, and the previous discussion applies.

Comment: Two *consistent* systems $A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{c}$ and $B\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{d}$ have the same set of solutions if and only if the rowspace of $A$ equals the rowspace of $B$. See [this previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/111757/742).