# Equivalent Systems of linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra

If two systems of linear equations have same solution set then can any equation of one system can be written into linear combinations of equations of other system?

Comment: Provided the systems are consistent then [yes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/111757/is-there-a-converse-for-the-following-theorem-equivalent-systems-of-linear-equa)

Comment: Can u please provide me a proof for it.

Comment: See the [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/111757/is-there-a-converse-for-the-following-theorem-equivalent-systems-of-linear-equa)

Comment: Thanks brother for help