# Systems of linear equations that have the same solutions are row-equivalent if the equations are over $\mathbb{Z}_n$?

Tags: linear-algebra, ring-theory, systems-of-equations

I have seen that this is true if the linear equations are over <$\mathbb{R}$ and extensions>([Is there a converse for the following Theorem? Equivalent systems of linear equations have exactly the same solutions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/111757/is-there-a-converse-for-the-following-theorem-equivalent-systems-of-linear-equa)).

But is it true if the equations are over a ring $\mathbb{Z}_n$?